# Validating third party API keys/basic authentication on Azure API Management?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-api-management

I am looking at using Azure API Management as a gateway to my API, and wish to handle the authentication on it entirely if possible. +

Currently I'm in the process of setting it up to validate JWTs using the `validate-jwt` policy from a third party OAuth provider, however I also need a way for server-to-server requests.

Ideally, I don't want the server to have to constantly regenerate tokens going through something like the client credentials flow. I would prefer if there were a **revocable** endless API key. While I could set it up to generate a JWT with no expiry, this isn't easily revocable.

I saw there is a policy `authenticate-basic` but from what I can see you need to hard-code or use secrets for the user/pass and can't have it query (and then cache) the details with a third party server.

I think I have seen something about making HTTP requests through policies, so maybe this is possible to do, and then have the API key cached to speed up following requests? I would like to do it this way since the authentication server is first-party meaning I can set it up to handle verification requests from APIM, and this would mean no authentication would need to be done on the micro services.

Has anyone tried implementing this before? I'm kind of thinking out loud as I type but the idea to have a policy send a HTTP request to the authorization server to verify an API key does seem promising to me (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/send-request-policy). If I were to go this route, is it possible using policies to restrict access to an endpoint dependent on the success of this HTTP request?

Comment: Subscription key is built in to API Management. Does this not fit your needs?

Comment: @TomW From what I can tell the subscription keys are very tied into the whole developer portal and first party account management side of things. I want to be able to use my own authorization server for it because there are other purposes I need it for that I don't believe can be done through the subscriptions approach. I want API key generation and management to be done through my own site so it can better integrate with the use cases I need it for.

Comment: Could you clarify, please, where the problem is exactly, do you want to authenticate customers calling to APIM using JWT, or are you looking for a way to make sure that your backend API can only be called via APIM?

Comment: I'm trying to authenticate customers using both JWT (users) and API keys (bots). The post is about authenticating the API keys, since it already has built-in support for validating JWTs

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, following your comment, you want to use revokeble API key authentication between APIM and your backend service. There are a few ways to do that.

1. If you're fine storing key in APIM configuration you could create backend entity (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/backends) in APIM, those are not only for Service Fabric. The benefit is that all your authentication information will be contained in that entity and all you need to do in policy is:

   `<set-backend-service backend-id="..." />`

   And APIM will take care of adding necessary headers with necessary values following backend entity configuration.
2. You can store key in a secret named value (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties) and use it's value as part of authenticate-basic or set-header or other policy to send key value to backend with each request.
3. You can do what you yourself are describing:

   c. Use send-request policy to call to external service

   b. Cache key from that response

   c. Attach key from response to request

   For that you'd want to familiarize with policy expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions It allows for writing custom request processing logic